# Counting the number of related objects with a certain value in Django

Tags: django, database, postgresql, indexing, denormalization

This are simplified models to demonstrate my problem:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    total_readers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Reader(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

So, we have `Users`, `Books` and `Readers` (`Users`, who have read a `Book`). Thus, `Reader` is basically a many-to-many relationship between `Book` and `User`.

Now let's say, the current user reads a book. Now, I'd like to update the number of total readers for *all* books of this book's author:

```
# get the book (as an example pk=1)
book = Book.objects.get(pk=1)

# save Reader object for this user and this book
Reader(user=request.user, book=book).save()

# count and save the total number of readers for this author in all his books
book.author.total_readers = Reader.objects.filter(book__author=book.author).count()
book.author.save()
```

By doing so, Django creates a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query for PostgreSQL and we get the expected result. However, the database tables are huge and this has become a bottleneck.

In this example, we could simply increase the `total_readers` by one on each view, instead of actually counting the database rows. However, this is just a simplified model structure and we cannot do this in reality here.

What I can do, is creating another field in the Reader model called `book_author_id`. Thus, I denormalize data and can count the Reader objects without having PostgreSQL making the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with the User table.
Finally, here's my question: Is it possible to create some sort of database index, so that PostgreSQL handles this denormalization automatically? Or do I really have to create this additional model field and redundantly store the author's PK in there?

EDIT - to point out the essential question: I got several great answers, which work for a lot of scenarios. However, they don't solve this actual problem. The only thing I'd like to know, is if it's possible to have PostgreSQL handle such a denormalization automatically - e.g. by creating some sort of database index.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, this query can serve better:

```
book.author.total_readers = Reader.objects.filter(book__in=Book.objects.filter(author=book.author)).count()
```

That will generate query with sub-query, sometimes it will have better performance that query with join. You even go further and end up creating 2 queries separately:

```
book.author.total_readers = Reader.objects.filter(book_id__in=Book.objects.filter(author=book.author).values_list('id', flat=True)).count()
```

That will generate 2 queries, one will retrieve list of all book IDs for that author and second will retrieve count of reads for books with ID in that list.

Comment: We use such an approach on a different model/problem. In this case, however, it won't make things easier. The example includes just the minimal part necessary to describe the problem. In reality, there's more to it, which renders this approach not so practical.

Comment: So if there is something more that will have impact on valid answer, please explain it in your question so answer can be more specified and related to your problem directly.

Answer (score 1):

It's always way better to solve bottlenecks of this sort with good design and maybe a little bit of caching rather than duplicating data in the way you suggest.  The total_readers field is data you should generate instead of recording.

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @property
    def total_readers(self):
        cached_value = caching_client.get("readers_"+self.username, None)
        if cached_value is None:
            cached_value = self.readers()
            caching_client.set("readers_"+self.username, 
                                cached_value)
        return cached_value

    def readers(self):
        return Reader.objects.filter(book__author__user=self).count()
```

There are libraries that do the caching via decorators but I felt it was a pattern you would benefit from seeing expressly.  You can also attach a TTL to the cache so that you insure that the value can't be wrong for longer than TTL.  You can also regenerate the cache upon creation of a Reader object.

You might actually get some mileage with declaring an m2m and defining through relationships but I have no experience of it.

Comment: Good idea, but won't work for us. There are millions of users/authors. Caching millions of entries is probably not a good idea ...

Comment: Millions of entries are only MBs.  You can also cache only the most-used data.  Caching is not a 100% solution to everything but it might alleviate your problem enough that it goes away (for now).

Comment: I managed to make a news website render almost every page within 50ms with caching tricks.  I stored fragments of html code in a namespace in such a way that making each page was mostly concatenating strings from cache.  If the string wasn't available it would be regenerated by the web dyno.  Almost all of the time workers behind the scenes kept the cache "warm". What resulted was that the most frequent query to the database was to update page hit count.

Answer (score 1):

Good solution also may be to create some batch task that will run for example once per hour and count up all reads, but that way you will end up with not live refreshing count of reads.

You can also create celery task that will run just after read is created to generate new value for author. That way you won't have long response time and delay from creating read to counting it up won't be so long.

Comment: This solution may improve the user experience, however, our goal is to reduce load on our database servers - which won't happen by using asynchronous processes. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You can also monitor asynchronous processes so there won't be 2 processes in queue for one author. Also, queue can have some delay between tasks and maybe reduced performance, so load over time will be lower.